# Determinant of an unknown matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $x, y$ be two real variables. If $A$ is any $n\times n$ matrix with all entries in the set $\{x,y\}$ then prove that
\begin{equation} 
\det A = (x-y)^{n-1}(Px + (-1)^{n-1}Qy)
\end{equation}
where $P,Q$ are integers defined by
\begin{equation} 
P = \det A\big|_{x=1,y=0} \quad Q = \det A\big|_{x=0,y=1}.
\end{equation}

I tried to do this by using induction and started for $n=2.$ But I am confused about the matrix that it will form since there are more than one possibility for a $2\times 2$ matrix. For example
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x & y  \\
    y & x 
  \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
    x & x  \\
    y & x 
  \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
    x & y  \\
    x & y 
  \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
    y & y  \\
    y & x 
  \end{bmatrix},...
\end{equation}
There are 12 more possibilities. I have checked couple of cases and the result holds but I have no idea how to prove it in generality without checking each case. I would really appreciate any help. Also if you can give me some reference from where this type of problem is taken that will also help me a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Indeed, for each $n$, you will have $2^{n^2}$ different matrix

Comment: My browser cannot render the terms in the exponents after "$n-"$.

Comment: Why start with $n=2$ instead of $n=1$. And then use the definition of $\det$ given by $\det (A )= \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1}A_{i,1} \det (A_{k,l})$ with $k \neq i$ and $l \neq 1$.

Comment: I was checking what this result is actually saying thats why I started with $n=2.$

Comment: @Hetebrij What is $A_{k,l}$ in this definition? Is this the Laplace's formula.

Comment: @Kumarm I believe the submatrix which you have to consider when using the [expansion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion)

Comment: It is Laplace's formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is clear that $\det A(x,y)$ is a homogeneous polynomial in $x,y$ of degree $n$. If we denote the matrix with all entries equal to $1$ by $M$, then $A=yM + (x-y)B$, with $B=A(1,0)$. Now $M$ is $n$ times a projection (on the vector with all $1$'s), so if we diagonalize, we obtain
$$
S^{-1}MS = n \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0_{n-1,n-1}\end{pmatrix} .
$$
Thus $(x-y)^{n-1}$ indeed divides
$$
\det A = \det (y S^{-1}MS + (x-y)S^{-1}BS ) ,
$$
because only one entry of the matrix on the RHS is not a multiple of $x-y$.

So we now know that
$$
\det A = (x-y)^{n-1} (ax + by) ,
$$
and we then confirm that $a,b$ are as asserted by comparing values at $x=0,y=1$ and $x=1,y=0$.

Comment: The name $Q$ for a matrix is not well chosen; it is already an integer in the statement of the question.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Well, I wanted to call it $P$ as in *projection*, but noticed that that name was taken...

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thank you.